# Is the EPP/Auth code confidential? Support rep asking for it to disable domain privacy

Tags: domain-transfer, bluehost

I have a domain name registered with Bluehost having their Domain Privacy enabled. The control panel is bugging and won't let me disable it, so I contacted the support via chat and they're asking me for the EPP code to disable the privacy.

As far as I understand,

- the EPP (Auth) code is required for transfers between registrars only, and shouldn't be needed for one registrar to disable a feature somewhere in their internal billing
- it is also a password of a kind, therefore the [*we'll never ask for your password*](https://www.facebook.com/help/117177641701328) logic should apply

The domain is pending transfer and is currently unlocked. So should I give the Bluehost rep my domain EPP code? Is it common for support to ask for an EPP code?

I was talking to them via [helpchat.bluehost.com](https://helpchat.bluehost.com/), so the chat platform seems legit, to my knowledge. I wanted to contact Bluehost regarding this, but they don't seem to offer e-mail support anymore.

Comment: Your assumption is correct and I am wondering if you are dealing with a properly-trained employee, or their admin panel has some strange requirements. But since you are saying the domain is pending transfer anyway, can't you wait until the transfer is complete to set up the whois, or is that hindering the transfer in some way ?

Comment: @Anonymous if domain privacy is enabled, it is possible to not receive the transfer approval email.

Comment: The E-mail address used for domain privacy is supposed to forward to your regular E-mail address - just test it.

Comment: @Anonymous, right, but in this exact case it just says "whois@bluehost.com", and apparently won't forward

Comment: Sounds like a customer retention tactic, like the fact you have to contact them to fix this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I ended up doing nothing since I initiated a transfer, and today I got an email from the receiving registrar saying it's completed. The whois database and the Bluehost panel now confirm this. So the Bluehost team must have approved the transfer request themselves. I did not give them any codes or anything.